# Compile Sass from an scss folder to a file at the root level of a project

Tags: css, sass, compilation

I have an scss folder, with my style.scss file inside it.  I would like the compiled .css file to be in the root of the project, effectively at the same level as the scss folder and index.html in the image provided below.

I know how to compile from one file to another:

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

and from one folder to another

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

I can't work out how to get sass to generate the .css file at the same (project root) level as the scss folder though?

When I do scss:./style.css it just creates a folder called style.css instead of a file with that name.

I tried using the > character, from one of the other answers but this didn't work either.

Here is a screenshot of the file structure.

[image]

Comment: Did you try actually specifying the output file you want?

Comment: Of course, I mentioned that above, but when i do sass --watch scss:./style.css I don't get the desired outcome.  If you know the solution please feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.  I needed to just do ./ as the file path. When I attempted this originally I did something very similar, but omitted the dot and just did /

So full code to get your output .css file generated in the root of the project from the scss folder is:

```
sass --watch scss:./
```